# Property chained binding not working in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, treeview

In my WPF PRISM (MEF) application, I am using chained binding (don't know if i am referring it correctly) of `RuleAppContainer.RuleApp.Rules` with TreeView control as shown below.

**View**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RuleAppContainer.RuleApp.Rules}">
</TreeView>
```

Now upon booting the application, `RuleAppContainer` singleton object is created by the MEF container whereas `RuleApp` property is null in the beginning. Later when the `RuleApp` is loaded by calling the AddRuleApp method inside RuleAppContainer, its not reflecting (rebinding) on TreeView.

**ViewModel**

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private RuleAppContainer _ruleAppContainer;
    public RuleAppContainer RuleAppContainer
    {
        get { return _ruleAppContainer; }
        protected set { SetProperty(ref _ruleAppContainer, value); }
    }
}
```

**Model (simplified) definitions**

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class RuleAppContainer : BindableBase
{
    private RuleApp _ruleApp;
    public RuleApp RuleApp
    {
        get { return _ruleApp; }
        private set { SetProperty(ref _ruleApp, value); }
    }

    public void AddRuleApp(RuleApp ruleApp)
    {
        RuleApp = ruleApp;
    }
}

public class RuleApp : ObjectBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<RuleFolder> Rules => 
        new ObservableCollection<RuleFolder>(GetRuleElements());

    public IEnumerable<RuleFolder> GetRuleElements()
    {
        foreach (var x in Entities.Where(x => x.RuleElements != null))
            yield return x.RuleElements;

        IEnumerable<RuleFolder> GetContextRuleElements(IEnumerable<EntityItem> items)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
                if (item.RuleElements != null)
                    yield return item.RuleElements;
        }

        foreach (var e in Entities)
            foreach (var f in GetContextRuleElements(e.Items))
                yield return f;

        if (_rules.Count > 0)
        {
            var ruleFolder = _rules[0];
            yield return ruleFolder;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it should work fine as i have tested it by creating a simple WPF application to validate.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Fyi: I have deleted my previous answer (relating to `Rules` returning a new collection every time it is being read), as it cannot be the solution to your problem, since you said that `GetRuleElements()` always returns at least one element, but the TreeView is not showing it.
When you run your program in Debug mode, do you see any binding errors in the "Output" pane?

Comment: Yes i checked but no errors, in fact i used this statement even to find any details but no luck `ItemsSource="{Binding RuleAppContainer.RuleApp.Rules, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"`

Comment: The strange part is a separate WPF sample is working fine with same approach. I don't know what is missing here.